# How to store RSA key pair of size 8192 in android

Tags: android, kotlin, rsa, key-pair

How to securely store the rsa keys generated with key size as 8192?   RSA keys generated using below code

```
val keyPair = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA")
keyPair.initialize(8192)
val keys = keyPair.generateKeyPair()
```

Is it possible to use Android KeyChain for storing public and private key?

Comment: You can use [EncryptedSharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/security/crypto/EncryptedSharedPreferences) to store sensitive data.

Comment: The preferred way to store asymmetric keys on Android is the hardware protected `AndroidKeystore`. Unfortunately it is restricted to RSA 4096 at maximum. So you have to decide to use a less secure storage and an RSA 8192 key or a secure storage with a state-of-the-art RSA 4096 bit key. According to https://www.keylength.com/en/compare/ an RSA 4096 bit key is at the moment considered secure up to the year 2050 and beyond.